# R merge without duplicating columns

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have two dataframes. For example

```
require('xlsx')
csvData <- read.csv("myData.csv")
xlsData <- read.xlsx("myData.xlsx")
```

csvData looks like this:

```
Period  CPI     VIX
1       0.029   31.740
2       0.039   32.840
3       0.028   34.720
4       0.011   43.740
5       -0.003  35.310
6       0.013   26.090
7       0.032   28.420
8       0.022   45.080
```

xlsData looks like this:

```
Period  CPI     DJIA
1       0.029   12176
2       0.039   10646
3       0.028   11407
4       0.011   9563
5       -0.003  10708
6       0.013   10776
7       0.032   9384
8       0.022   7774
```

When I merge this data, the CPI data is duplicated, and a suffix is put on the header, which is problematic (I have many more columns in my real df's).

```
mergedData <- merge(xlsData, csvData, by = "Period")
```

mergedData:

```
Period  CPI.x   VIX     CPI.y   DJIA
1       0.029   31.740  0.029   12176
2       0.039   32.840  0.039   10646
3       0.028   34.720  0.028   11407
4       0.011   43.740  0.011   9563
5       -0.003  35.310  -0.003  10708
6       0.013   26.090  0.013   10776
7       0.032   28.420  0.032   9384
8       0.022   45.080  0.022   7774
```

I want to merge the data frames without duplicating columns with the same name. For example, I want this kind of output:

```
Period  CPI     VIX     DJIA
1       0.029   31.740  12176
2       0.039   32.840  10646
3       0.028   34.720  11407
4       0.011   43.740  9563
5       -0.003  35.310  10708
6       0.013   26.090  10776
7       0.032   28.420  9384
8       0.022   45.080  7774
```

I don't want to have to use additional 'by' arguments, or dropping columns from one of the df's, because there are too many columns that are duplicated in both df's. I'm just looking for a dynamic way to drop those duplicated columns during the merge process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can skip the `by` argument if the common columns are named the same.

From `?merge`:

> By default the data frames are merged on the columns with names they both have, but separate specifications of the columns can be given by `by.x` and `by.y`.

Keeping that in mind, the following should work (as it did on your sample data):

```
merge(csvData, xlsData)
#   Period    CPI   VIX  DJIA
# 1      1  0.029 31.74 12176
# 2      2  0.039 32.84 10646
# 3      3  0.028 34.72 11407
# 4      4  0.011 43.74  9563
# 5      5 -0.003 35.31 10708
# 6      6  0.013 26.09 10776
# 7      7  0.032 28.42  9384
# 8      8  0.022 45.08  7774
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize "by" was optional. What if my df's are of different length? For example, suppose csvData had only 7 rows. I want to keep all the data from xlsData. Then cbind the csvData (NULL is fine for row 8 corresponding to csvData).

Comment: @Clark, use `all = TRUE` perhaps? Example: `merge(csvdata[1:7, ], xlsdata, all = TRUE)`

Comment: I realized that when there are multiple common variables in the data.frames, it does not worrk? Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You can also index your specific column of interest by name. This is useful if you just need a single column/vector from a large data frame.

```
Period <- seq(1,8)
CPI <- seq(11,18)
VIX <- seq(21,28)
DJIA <- seq(31,38)
Other1 <- paste(letters)[1:8]
Other2 <- paste(letters)[2:9]
Other3 <- paste(letters)[3:10]

df1<- data.frame(Period,CPI,VIX)
df2<- data.frame(Period,CPI,Other1,DJIA,Other2,Other3)

merge(df1,df2[c("Period","DJIA")],by="Period") 

> merge(df1,df2[c("Period","DJIA")],by="Period")
  Period CPI VIX DJIA
1      1  11  21   31
2      2  12  22   32
3      3  13  23   33
4      4  14  24   34
5      5  15  25   35
6      6  16  26   36
7      7  17  27   37
8      8  18  28   38
```