# SparkR merge without creating duplicate columns

Tags: r, apache-spark, dataframe, merge, sparkr

I decided to create this question because [the answer provided to a very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457835/r-merge-without-duplicating-columns) problem does not work for my scenario:

I want to merge these two SparkR dataframes df1

```
col1    col2    
1       11      
2       22      
3       33      
4       44
```

and df2

```
col1    col2    newcol
1       11      401
2       22      402
3       33      403
4       44      404
```

The dfs should be merged on columns 1 and 2. I tried all steps proposed in the link above (e.g. omitting "by" statement), but the result always looks like this:

```
col1_x  col2_x  col1_y  col2_y  newcol
1       11      1       11      401
2       22      2       22      402
3       33      3       33      403
4       44      4       44      404
```

I don't want to have duplicate columns and for now I have to delete col1_y, col2_y manually and rename col1_x, col2_x to only have col1, col2 and newcol as result:

```
df <- merge(df1, df2)  # <- how can I change this?
df$col1_y <- NULL
df$col2_y <- NULL
df <- withColumnRenamed(df, "col1_x", "col1")
df <- withColumnRenamed(df, "col2_x", "col2")
```

I tried all kinds of combinations using the by, by.x and by.y statement but none worked. **Is there a way I can simplify this tedious correction chain by omitting one of the steps?** Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, one option is to `select()` relevant columns from the resulting `DataFrame`:

```
library(magrittr) 

# We'll use join to avoid suffixes '_x' & '_y'
join(df1,df2,(df1$col1==df2$col1)&(df1$col2==df2$col2)) %>%
  select(df1$col1,df1$col2,df2$newcol) %>%
  showDF()
#+----+----+------+
#|col1|col2|newcol|
#+----+----+------+
#|   1|11.0|   401|
#|   2|22.0|   402|
#|   3|33.0|   403|
#|   4|55.0|   404|
#+----+----+------+
```